# compiling modern emacs-23 on a linux box with no root privileges

Tags: linux, installation, emacs

I am trying to compile emacs-23.4 on a Linux box with no root privileges, and I got stuck at this point:

```
../emacs-23.4/configure      --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
[...]
make -j32
[...]
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXaw
make[1]: *** [temacs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/src/emacs/latest/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

I also tried with gtk, but also got stuck with it:

checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.6 glib-2.0 >= 2.6... no

```
../emacs-23.4/configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
[...]
configure: error: Package xau was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xau.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xau', required by 'XCB', not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try building it with gtk support in stead of with the Athena toolkit.

```
./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
make -j8
```

([source](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/app-editors/emacs/emacs-23.4-r1.ebuild?view=markup))

PS: Do you actually have 16+ cores available on your build box?

#### Edit:

If that doesn't work either, you could try to disable the X functionality altogether with

```
./configure --without-x --without-ns --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
```

#### Edit2:

Or, even better, do

```
./configure --help
```

and disable everything you don't *really* want and know you have the deps for in the "Optional Packages: " section.

Comment: edited now, it seems there is also a problem trying to do it with gtk.

Comment: I can do it without, but still looking forward to a way of having it with gtk or similar.